# Why does MySQL allow to update a NOT NULL column to NULL?

Tags: mysql

I'm running `MySql` in `ubuntu 10.10`. I created a table called `'employee'` having 3 field names **empno, name and salary**. Inserted few entities. In the middle of the process i want to change salary attribute as `'NOT NULL'`. I Alter the table as

```
ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY salary int(10) NOT NULL;
```

Query executed. I wanted to test by using command,

```
UPDATE employee SET salary=NULL;

Query OK, 15 rows affected, 15 warnings (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 15  Changed: 15  Warnings: 15
```

also gave warnings  `"  (Code 1048): Column 'salary' cannot be null  "`(Repeated for every row)

But when i saw my table , All salaries were Zeros(`'0'`).

**Same queries result in error instead of warning in WINDOWS XP's MySql**

I checked in both INNODB and MYISAM engines but same Result. 
Please help me to know what happened beside processing.

Comment: What is your question? You set your field to `not null` and you set it to NULL. It will default to `0` as is expected. What are they doing in windows according to you? Setting the field to `NULL`? That would be weird.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "working well in `XP`"?

Comment: @Nanne and @ Quassnoi In windows it doesn't allow null values to update and shows original salaries, but here it is showing all zeros. Yes, it may be weird but for me results were unexpected. :)

Comment: What did you use to perform the query, just a commandline mysql client? What do you mean "it doens't allow"? You're getting an error instead of a warning?

Comment: can you edit your question and show the output of this command: show create table employee;

Comment: @Nanne yes, commadline mysql client. In Windows it is giving ERROR.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must not have `SQL_MODE` set to strict on you ubuntu installation.

Issue

```
SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

or add

```
SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

under `[mysqld]` to your `my.cnf` on `Ubuntu`.

Comment: +1 That was awesome.:) but where did i get my.cnf file in ubuntu?

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I believe but you better check.

Comment: That was correct path but it is saying "could not save file under /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Save under a Different name? "

Comment: @kik: it's not world-editable, as you can figure. Run the editor under `sudo`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the problem, you set the column to `NOT NULL`, (which doesn't allow NULL values) and now it won't let you set it to `NULL`, which would be the expected behaviour.

The reason you have 0s in your DB is because 0 would be the result of casting NULL to an int.

Comment: Result of casting `NULL` to an `INT` is a `NULL`.

Comment: +1 for clarified almost. But why it is not performing same in windows? why it is giving Zeros in UBUNTU? :)

Comment: I think Quassnoi has nailed it :)