# phpMyAdmin Accepts NULL in the NOT NULL field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I've created a table with some NOT NULL columns using phpMyAdmin.

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST` (`ID` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                     `Firstname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
                     `Lastname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)
```

There is no problem with INSERT operation. Database prevent to set a NULL field properly.

```
INSERT INTO `TEST`(`Firstname`, `Lastname`) VALUES ("Peter", null)

#1048 - Column 'Lastname' cannot be null
```

The accepted one is:

```
INSERT INTO `TEST`(`Firstname`, `Lastname`) VALUES ("Peter", "Smith")

1 row inserted. 
Inserted row id: 1 (Query took 0.0004 sec)
```

But after I've created a record with non-NULL fields successfully, database allows me to UPDATE these fields to NULL.

```
UPDATE `TEST` SET `Lastname`=NULL WHERE `ID` = 1

1 row affected. (Query took 0.0006 sec)
```

I've tried "NULL" and 'NULL' as well, but database put them in the field as a string.

I'm really confused about this issue. Is this a phpMyAdmin bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MySQL allow to update a NOT NULL column to NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702786/why-does-mysql-allow-to-update-a-not-null-column-to-null)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A constraint to prevent the insert of an empty string in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You must not have SQL_MODE set to strict on your installation.

Issue

```
SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

or add

```
SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

under **`[mysqld]`** into your **`my.cnf`**

To find my.cnf, look in the MySQL config file `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini.`

At the top of that file are some comments:

```
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
```

There it tells you where to find your `my.cnf` file.

Restart your mysql if necessary.

Comment: I've tried the command on phpMyAdmin. It's executed properly, but still accept NULL on update. the problem hasn't solved.where should I run this code?

Comment: Yes, I've already read the article. thanks for the link. but I'm using online phpMyAdmin and I don't have access to any .cnf or .ini file to change them.

Comment: @ChristianMark even in my case the change does not work, instead it stops my MySQLDatabase from starting completely

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the rights to change the SQL mode via phpMyAdmin. Go the home (starting) page of phpMyAdmin, then click on Variables and enter "SQL mode" in the filter. Then you have access to some explanations via the question mark, and by clicking on this line you can edit the value of SQL mode and save it.

However this would be just for testing purposes, at the setting will revert to its original value once the server is restarted; hence the need to change the configuration file.

Comment: I've tried SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES', but it didn't work.also tried SET @@global.sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES', and this one required SUPER privilege(s), Unfortunately I don't have.