# MySQL: Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql, windows-8, odbc, sql-insert

First of all, I googled this question but didn't find any similar situations.
So I appreсiate any help.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tinypurses.purses (
  id SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  keyyy CHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  LastSeed SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX purses_id_index (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

When I try insert a new record into it, I got an error:

*Database error: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.47-community]Column 'LastSeed' cannot be null*

I'm confused because I explicitly set value for column 'LastSeed':

```
statement.prepare(connection(), "insert into purses (time, keyyy, LastSeed) values(?, ?, ?)");
statement.param(1).set_as_systemtime(sysTime);
statement.param(2).set_as_string(key);
statement.param(3).set_as_long(1);
if (!stmt.execute())
{
    LOG << statement.last_error(); // got this error here
}
```

Moreover, this code works fine on Windows XP and 7, but not on Windows 8 (with the same version of MySQL server).

Does anybody have any ideas why it works on a such strange manner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the field name as "key" . it's a keyword of mysql.

Comment: ok, I failed, but I renamed not related columns when posted initial question. I got this error even if column has a valid name.

Comment: yeah, it works fine on XP and 7. Looks like used version of MySQL Server or ODBC connector is very old for Windows 8 - something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you didn't explicitly set value for column `LastSeed`, setting a `DEFAULT` constraint in the field definition (as you do) should suffice.

Since you say that it works on other versions of Windows, and since the error is obviously irrelevant, I would investigate the ODBC driver installed.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL on Win XP thru Win 7 by default behave incorrectly with regards to NULL values and whether or not it will allow an insert of a NULL value. ie: on windows MySQL by default will allow an insert of a NULL value into a NOT NULL field.  [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703260/1625932)

MySQL on *nix and apparently now Win 8 behave correctly.  The reason that you can not insert '0' into a NOT NULL field is because in MySQL '0' === NULL.

[3.3.4.6. Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: As the documentation you linked to shows, 0 and '0' (and any other value) are both not NULL